# prepareForSegue is not called from UITableViewController

Tags: ios6, uitableview

I have started iOS app development recently.

I have a problem about segue from UITableViewController to UIViewController. 
"prepareForSegue" is not called when a tablecell is clicked.

It seems to me that the code and interface builder settings are fine.
Segue ID is properly set. I also embedded UITableVC in navigationVC, too. 
I set the breakpoint in the prepareForSegue, but it does not stop there and no log is generated.

Through researching tips in the Internet, I understand that using didSelectRowAtIndexPath is one of the solutions for my problem.
But I would like to understand the solution by using storyboard.

This might be a basic question, but if someone could give me some tips, it could be very helpful.

thank you,

```
@interface test2TVC ()
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@end

@implementation test2TVC
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.items = @[@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", @"item4",
               @"item5", @"item6", @"item7", @"item8"];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"test log");
}  

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you pushed the segue on your tableview??

Comment: Is your segue from the UITableView Prototype cell to the destination View Controller in storyboard?

Comment: Krishna and codeInOrange, thank you very much for commenting to my question! Yes, I pushed UITableViewController to destination ViewController. Instead of using accessary action. Segue is pushed from UITableViewCell not from UITableViewController in storyboard.

Comment: I did not use UITableViewCell. Segue is pushed from tableview cell area in UITableViewController in storyboard. This is very simple and basic function in UITableViewController. The setting should be simple, but I still struggling the problem. prepareForSegue is not called...

Answer (score 1):

When I use:

[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
in viewDidLoad

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]  in cellForRowAtIndexPath

prepareForSegue will not be called.

When I remove registerClass line in viewDidLoad, and

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, prepareForSegue will be called, other setting are all same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have embedded navigation controller your UITableViewController in Mainstoryboard. or try to embed navigation controller in rootViewController of your project. Then set reuse identifier in tableviewcell. Any problem the please share it.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me advice. I made sure that UITableViewContoroller was embedded in navigation controller. But prepareForSegue was not called. Then, I deleted UITableViewController and UINavigationController, and tried to use RootViewController(drag it from xCode utility area). But unfortunately, it did not work well, again. Its reuse identifier, segue identifier seems fine. Segue from UITableViewController to destinationViewController are push (not accessary action). UITableViewController and UIViewController are properly assigned to each view controller class.